# Using .isin function to produce boolean results of whether a value is listed anywhere in different column

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a sample dataframe from a much larger set of data. I need to create a new column `'Is a Manager?'`, that contains boolean results `'True'` or `'False'`. The condition; is the `'Employee ID'` listed anywhere within the `'Manager ID'` column within the dataset?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Worker': ['Sam','Tom','Justin','Jake'], 'Employee ID':[12345,12121,67891,99991], 'Manager ID': [97483, 29601,85863, 19739]})
df

    Worker  Employee ID Manager ID
0   Sam     12345       97483
1   Tom     12121       29601
2   Justin  67891       85863
3   Jake    99991       19739
 and so on....
```

I have tried to use the `.isin` function.

The column was added successfully, but all values state `False`, when I know some should be `True`.

For example, Sam's Employee ID `12345` is listed on line 245 as person X's manager `'Manager ID' = 12345`

Any idea where i've gone wrong? My code is:

```
df3 = df.loc[:, ['Worker', 'Employee ID', 'Manager ID']]
df3.insert(1, 'Is a Manager?', df3['Employee ID'].isin(['Manager ID']))
df3

Worker  Is a Manager?   Employee ID Manager ID
0   A      False       221113      1210236
1   B      False       221359      86082653
2   C      False       295142      1718020
3   D      False       775199      1910236
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`df3.insert(1, 'Is a Manager?', df3['Employee ID'].isin(['Manager ID']))`

You are checking whether the Employee ID is in a list containing the string `"Manager ID"`.

The line should be:

`df3.insert(1, 'Is a Manager?', df3['Employee ID'].isin(df3['Manager ID']))`

Comment: Thanks so much! A very easy fix